# Azure policies prohibiting permissions at the management group level

Tags: azure, azure-policy

in order to more efficiently manage permissions on the Azure platform, I have been assigned Contributor and RBAC Administrator permissions at the level of Management Groups in which there are several subscriptions.

However, I would like to be able to continue assigning permissions only at the Resource Group/Resource level.

I managed to create an Azure Policy that effectively gives access to it at the Resource Group/Resource level, but it is still possible to assign permissions to the Management Groups themselves.

Has anyone encountered such a problem and can suggest a possible solution?

Best Regards
Jacek

The policy works for subscriptions/rg (prohibits adding permissions), but not for management groups:

```
"policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "value": "[startsWith(field('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/scope'),concat(subscription().id,'/resourceGroups'))]",
                "equals": "false"
              },
              {
                "value": "[contains(field('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/scope'),'managementGroups')]",
                "equals": "true"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
      }
    }
```

I tried without the second rule in anyOf but it still doesn't work.

[Management Group Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFq9M.png)

[Root Management Group Policy Assigne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C94Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

> I managed to create an Azure Policy that effectively gives access to it at the Resource Group/Resource level, but it is still possible to assign permissions to the Management Groups themselves.

The below policy will deny the role assignments at the `Management Group` level but it will allow the role assignment at resource group and subscription level.

> Note: To prevent role assignments within the `Management Group`, apply the policy at the level of the `Management Group` itself.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/principalId",
            "exists": "false"
          }
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "value": "[contains(field('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/scope'), 'managementGroups/')]",
              "equals": "false"
            },
            {
              "value": "[startsWith(field('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/scope'), concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/'))]",
              "equals": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

The policy detected a non-compliance issue with someone who had access at the management group level.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I can still grant permissions at the group management level and I would not like to have this option. 

My goal is to prevent permissions from being assigned to the management group. 

The above policy meets 2 of the 3 assumptions, I cannot assign permissions at the subscription level (this is correct) and I can assign permissions at the Resource Group level (this is correct).

Comment: Have you assigned policy on Management Group level?

Comment: yes, I have set up a policy at the management group level to which the user has Contributor and RBAC Administrator access.

Comment: How many management groups do you have in your tenant?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my management groups structure to my post.

Comment: Kindly assign your policy to the Root Management Group to restrict role assignments on management groups.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: As per screen shot , you dont have access on root management group.

Comment: I have an access. I apply policies from the administrator level and test them on a user who should not have the above-mentioned access. Does this policy work for you?

Comment: Please check the policy assignment scope and share the policy assignment screenshot to check the issue.

Comment: The policy is correctly assigned, I added a screenshot to the post.